# How to enter insert mode when entering Neovim terminal pane?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, insert-mode

I have the following mappings to make it easy to move out of a terminal pane in Neovim:

```
tnoremap <C-h> <C-\><C-n><C-w>h
" Workaround since <C-h> isn't working in Neovim right now
tnoremap <C-w>h <C-\><C-n><C-w>h
tnoremap <C-j> <C-\><C-n><C-w>j
tnoremap <C-k> <C-\><C-n><C-w>k
tnoremap <C-l> <C-\><C-n><C-w>l
```

The only problem is that when I move back into the terminal pane, I have to press `i` to get back into insert mode. I always want it to be in insert mode when I move into a Neovim pane that is running terminal. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A terminal buffer name always starts with `term://`:

`autocmd BufWinEnter,WinEnter term://* startinsert`

Note that this will always put you in insert mode when you move to the terminal window, regardless of the mode you were using when leaving the window.

---

You can also use a similar autocommand to always get back in normal mode when you leave the terminal window, no matter how you leave this window:

`autocmd BufLeave term://* stopinsert`

Comment: With this solution, I experience [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15966/strange-behaviour-of-autocmd) problem. Would you know of a way around it?

Comment: The `BufEnter` autocmd looks like it does not have this problem.

Comment: This did not work for me, but this answer (https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22956/13656) did

Comment: The first autocmd only worked for me when I switched the command to `silent! normal i`.

Comment: for those using lua


`vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "TermOpen", "WinEnter term://*" }, { command = "startinsert" })`
```

Comment: @WillMunn doesn't work for me, gives `Invalid 'event': 'WinEnter term://*'`

Comment: The correct lua command is actually this: `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "TermOpen", "WinEnter" }, { pattern = "term://*", command = "startinsert" })`

Answer (score 16):

On neovim, you can do:

```
          autocmd TermOpen * startinsert
```

Found in `:help :terminal` .

Answer (score 3):

Entering a terminal buffer sets `buftype` to terminal, you can actually use this instead:

```
:au BufEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | :startinsert | endif
```

Comment: I found that :startinsert does not work for native vim 8 terminals as of this post. It is actually explicitly stated in `:help terminal` that, ":startinsert is ineffective." I found that `exec 'normal! i'` works instead.

Comment: "I found that :startinsert does not work for native vim 8 terminals as of this post." That's sad. Vim has lots to learn from NeoVim.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of answers in this thread do not support reopening terminal buffer back. This autocmd will always enter terminal mode upon opening the terminal buffer.

In Lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "TermOpen", "BufEnter" }, {
    pattern = { "*" },
    callback = function()
        if vim.opt.buftype:get() == "terminal" then
            vim.cmd(":startinsert")
        end
    end
})
```

Or in Vimscript:

```
:au TermOpen,BufEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | :startinsert | endif
```

Comment: That may not be desirable, though: perhaps I entered terminal normal mode, switched windows, and came back (and I don't want to lose my place by jumping to the input part of the job).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I agree, but the author mentioned "_I always want it to be in insert mode when I move into a neovim pane that is running terminal_"

Comment: Fair! Totally forgot the OP had this (odd) goal

Answer (score 1):

Or even slightly better:

```
  function! TerminalOptions()
    " /* folded code */
    silent! au BufEnter <buffer> startinsert!
    silent! au BufLeave <buffer> stopinsert!
  endfunction
  au TerminalOpen * call TerminalOptions()
```

Which the `<buffer>` will make the au command to be applied locally, so only for the termial buffer type. This is also usefull for changing so setting for the terminal only. Such as swtich from relative lines to absolute ;)

Also..... I cant get `:startinsert` to work, even if all docs point to that. I had to do the following:

```
    au BufEnter <buffer> exec "normal! i"
```

Comment: Note that `silent` needs to be `silent!` and go before the actual command, e.g. I ended up with `autocmd BufEnter <buffer> silent! exec "normal! i"`. (Vim 8.2)

Comment: Thanks !  I've update the post ;)