# NeoVim - Go into insert mode when clicking in a terminal in a pane?

Tags: neovim, insert-mode, terminal-buffer

I'm trying to use NeoVim as a tmux replacement, and have found that no matter what I do, I can't get it to go into insert mode when I click in a pane that has a terminal in it.

Here's the config I'm trying to use, with no luck.
Currently the config lets me navigate between panes, and when I enter the pane using the keyboard it switches to insert mode.

But when I enter the pane by clicking the mouse, it goes back to normal mode, which I almost never want.

#### ~/.config/nvim/init.vim

```
set mouse=a

if has('nvim')
    autocmd TermOpen term://* startinsert
    autocmd TermEnter term://* startinsert
    autocmd BufEnter term://* startinsert
endif

" Edit files within Nvim's terminal without nesting sessions.
augroup prevent_nested_edit
  autocmd VimEnter * if !empty($NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS) && $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS !=# v:servername
          \ |let g:r=jobstart(['nc', '-U', $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS],{'rpc':v:true})
          \ |let g:f=fnameescape(expand('%:p'))
          \ |noau bwipe
          \ |call rpcrequest(g:r, "nvim_command", "edit ".g:f)
          \ |call rpcrequest(g:r, "nvim_command", "call lib#SetNumberDisplay(1)")
          \ |qa
          \ |endif
augroup END
```

NOTE: I have found very similar questions, but they don't seem to work for when I "click" in the terminal - they work for navigating into the terminal pane with the keyboard:

[How to enter insert mode when entering neovim terminal pane?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3670/9850)

Comment: What if you did something like `nnoremap <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse>i` ?

Comment: @Ben Knoble - tried various flavors of that, and none of them worked - just tried that one too, and still a no go

Comment: It's a known [issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8691).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neovim's terminal has "a specialty": a mouse click automatically switches it to "Terminal-Normal" mode. (BTW. That's not a case for Vim, so it does not suffer from this issue.)

So it won't work from `<LeftMouse>`, but we can map `<LeftRelease>` instead:

```
if has('nvim')
    augroup terminal_setup | au!
        autocmd TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer><LeftRelease> <LeftRelease>i
        " more stuff
    augroup end
endif
```

Comment: awesome! thanks @Matt ! that totally worked!

Comment: for lua version: https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim/pull/523/files#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R550-R552