# Positioning the terminal emulator cursor in Neovim

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer, cursor

When in Normal mode in a Terminal buffer (as in :terminal) there's the Neovim's cursor and the shell's cursor. Going into Terminal-mode forgets your Neovim cursor and you're then using the shell's cursor where you left it.

Can I have it work like standard Vi, where you start inserting where your cursor is (unless not on the current modifiable command-line)? And have I/A take you to the start/end of the command line before putting you in Terminal-mode?

Comment: `like standard Vi` Vi does not have "a terminal". It's Vim. Also Vim's terminal actually has two modes: "terminal" and "terminal-normal" just like Neovim. The only difference is that Neovim often switches to "terminal-normal" automatically, while Vim expects for `ctrl-\_crl-n` or such. So I don't quite understand your question: maybe what you want is [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22307/neovim-go-into-insert-mode-when-clicking-in-a-terminal-in-a-pane)?

Comment: @Matt I talking about like :terminal. [This](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/neovim-terminal-paste) shows the cursors I mean  (1:34 - 2:00 in the video).