# Lua Conversion: Disable highlight after search when a motion is triggered or when entering insert mode

Tags: neovim, init.lua, init.vim

Author: [@purpleP](https://github.com/purpleP) 
Source: [Turn off highlight on CursorMoved and InsertEnter without remapping (doesn't break search operator pending mode)](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool/issues/9#issue-196870339)

```
noremap <expr> <Plug>(StopHL) execute('nohlsearch')[-1]
noremap! <expr> <Plug>(StopHL) execute('nohlsearch')[-1]

fu! HlSearch()
    let s:pos = match(getline('.'), @/, col('.') - 1) + 1
    if s:pos != col('.')
        call StopHL()
    endif
endfu

fu! StopHL()
    if !v:hlsearch || mode() isnot 'n'
        return
    else
        sil call feedkeys("\<Plug>(StopHL)", 'm')
    endif
endfu

augroup SearchHighlight
au!
    au CursorMoved * call HlSearch()
    au InsertEnter * call StopHL()
augroup end
```

**For my init.lua config, I need this in Lua.**

PS: I'm a newbie. Tried this for the first time. Please add some fixes to it.

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<expr> <Plug>(StopHL)', "execute('nohlsearch')[-1]", { noremap = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<expr> <Plug>(StopHL)', "execute('nohlsearch')[-1]", { noremap = true })

function HlSearch()
    local pos = vim.fn.match(vim.fn.getline('.'), @/, vim.fn.col('.') - 1) + 1
    if pos ~= vim.fn.col('.') then
        StopHL()
    end
end

function StopHL()
    if not vim.v.hlsearch or vim.fn.mode() ~= 'n' then
        return
    else
        vim.cmd[[silent! call feedkeys("\<Plug>(StopHL)", 'm')]]
    end
end

vim.cmd('augroup SearchHighlight')
vim.cmd('autocmd!')
vim.cmd('autocmd CursorMoved * lua HlSearch()')
vim.cmd('autocmd InsertEnter * lua StopHL()')
vim.cmd('augroup end')
```

Error messages:

```
Error detected while processing /home/killerbee/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5112: Error while creating lua chunk: /home/killerbee/.config/nvim/init.lua:7: unexpected symbol near '@'
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the symptoms of failure. It helps to know if we have been able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I think you need to find out how to access registers in Lua, because `@/` is Vim syntax for getting a register value (there are also functions like `getreg()`/`getreginfo()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another attempt:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<Plug>(StopHL)', "execute('nohlsearch')[-1]", { noremap = true, expr = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<Plug>(StopHL)', "execute('nohlsearch')[-1]", { noremap = true, expr = true })

function HlSearch()
    local pos = vim.fn.match(vim.fn.getline('.'), vim.fn.getreg('/'), vim.fn.col('.') - 1) + 1
    if pos ~= vim.fn.col('.') then
        StopHL()
    end
end

function StopHL()
    if not vim.v.hlsearch or vim.fn.mode() ~= 'n' then
        return
    else
        vim.cmd[[silent! call feedkeys("\<Plug>(StopHL)", 'm')]]
    end
end

local searchHighlightGrp = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('SearchHighlight', { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"CursorMoved"}, {group = searchHighlightGrp, pattern = '*', callback = HlSearch})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"InsertEnter"}, {group = searchHighlightGrp, pattern = '*', callback = StopHL})
```

Comment: I think this goes more with Lua if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first version that is working:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<Plug>(StopHL)', "execute('nohlsearch')[-1]", { noremap = true, expr = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<Plug>(StopHL)', "execute('nohlsearch')[-1]", { noremap = true, expr = true })

function HlSearch()
    print('HlSearch')
    local pos = vim.fn.match(vim.fn.getline('.'), vim.fn.getreg('/'), vim.fn.col('.') - 1) + 1
    if pos ~= vim.fn.col('.') then
        StopHL()
    end
end

function StopHL()
    print('StopHL')
    if not vim.v.hlsearch or vim.fn.mode() ~= 'n' then
        return
    else
        vim.cmd[[silent! call feedkeys("\<Plug>(StopHL)", 'm')]]
    end
end

vim.cmd('augroup SearchHighlight')
vim.cmd('autocmd!')
vim.cmd('autocmd CursorMoved * lua HlSearch()')
vim.cmd('autocmd InsertEnter * lua StopHL()')
vim.cmd('augroup end')
```

Comment: So close, yet missed it. Thanks a million.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Step by step you'll make it ;-)